# Facebook Access Token - reading multiple sources

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql

Let's say I want to read posts from CNN facebook page (id=5550296508) and BBC News facebook page (id=228735667216) for last 24 hours. Then FQL query would looks like this:

`SELECT post_id, message
FROM stream
WHERE (created_time > (now()-86400) 
AND
((source_id=5550296508 and actor_id=5550296508) OR (source_id=228735667216 and actor_id=228735667216 )))
limit 200`

You can try Graph/FQL explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ to see that this query works.

But, it works only when I obtain token by generating it from "Graph API Explorer". (Graph Api Explorer -> In the top menu -> Application: Graph Api Explorer is selected) When I generate token for my app, it never works. When I use app token, then it throw:

> "(#606) Queries for multiple source_ids require a non-zero viewer that has granted read_stream permission"

When I use user token, then it does not throw error, but it sends back empty JSON. Which looks like wrong permission setting, but it is not the case - when you use Graph Api Explorer you can select which permission should be enabled, I tried enabled all permissions - still JSON was empty.

When I'm requesting only one source pre query, it works, but I don't want to do that this way. Does someone understand why "Graph API Explorer" token works and other tokens not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you tried initially with an application access token (an application does not represent a user thus the non zero warning) then tried with a user access token from an application that didn't have the querying power of the Graph API Explorer app.

That is, the Graph API Explorer seems to have some consistency where the other apps fail with the same complex query. Call it a bug, call it preferential treatment.

Try using a multi query instead.

Comment: I tested this with one of my apps, and it's as @phwd says... Strange behaviour. Try two different queries per actor_id and source_id combination...